# Negative Lookahead to match a string unless it appears in specific words.

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a way to determine if a line contains a particular string, while at the same time not matching if it occurs in certain words. I have this partially working, however it fails if one of the exclude words begins with the keyword.

So for example, this regex:
   `^((?!custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic).)*(tom)`

will successfully exclude all the words listed, with the exception of tomcat & tomorrow. I'm assuming this is because i am matching the keyword, so the lookahead is failing, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: So you want to find `tom` but not if it is a part of `tomorrow`, etc..?  Do you just want the word `tom`, or should it also match `tommy`, etc..?

Comment: Correct. Basically i want to find any instance of 'tom' that appears on a line, whether by itself or as part of another word, except if it appears in that list of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
\b(?!(?:custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic)\b)[a-z]*tom[a-z]*\b
```

I used a word boundary (`\b`) instead of the anchor (`^`) so it will find the word anywhere, not just at the beginning.  Adding another `\b` to the end insures that it only matches complete words.

The `\b` at the end of the lookahead subexpression does the same for the filtered words.  For example, it won't match `automatic`, but it *will* match `automatically`.

Once the lookahead passes, `[a-z]*tom[a-z]*\b` matches a word (or more accurately, a continuous sequence of letters) that contains the `tom`.  I'm making a lot of simplifying assumptions so I can concentrate on the technique.  Most importantly, if your "words" can contain non-word characters like hyphens (`-`) or apostrophes (`'`), `[a-z]*` and `\b` might not be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** sadly, I haven't been able to figure this out unless you put the negative lookahead on both sides of the `.` in the non-capturing group:

```
^(?:(?!custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic).(?!custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic))*?(tom).*
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bY2tA8)

---

It works if you move the `.` before your negative lookahead: `.(?!...)`

I would also make the `*` [repetition lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), so it doesn't need to backtrack as much (not always true, but is in this example).  Also, if you want to match the entire line and only capture the instance of `tom`, make the group containing `.(?!...)` [non-capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and finish the expression with a greedy `.*`:

```
^(?:.(?!custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic))*?(tom).*
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nD6mI6)

Comment: This looks like its going in the right direction. This fails to match if the word appears as the first thing on the line though. In your example, 'but wait, automatic' is not a match (which is correct) but 
'automatic' matches.

Comment: @user3684999 see my update, I failed at coming up with anything less wordy..but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

This situation sounds straight out of [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).

Compared with other potential solutions, the regex couldn't be simpler:

```
custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic|(tom)
```

If you want to show not just `tom` but the whole word it is in, such as `tomahawk`, change this to:

```
custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic|(\w*tom\w*)
```

The left side of the alternation matches the words you don't want. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures `tom` to Group 1, and we know they are the right `tom` because they were not matched by the expressions on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/MPhQCo)). It finds `tom` and `tomahawk`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.List;

class Program {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {

String subject = "custom onetomany manytomany atom tomcat tomorrow automatic tom tomahawk";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("custom|onetomany|manytomany|atom|tomcat|tomorrow|automatic|(\\w*tom\\w*)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subject);
List<String> group1Caps = new ArrayList<String>();

// put Group 1 captures in a list
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
if(regexMatcher.group(1) != null) {
group1Caps.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
} // end of building the list

System.out.println("\n" + "*** Matches ***");
if(group1Caps.size()>0) {
for (String match : group1Caps) System.out.println(match);
}

} // end main
} // end Program
```

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment, posted in the wrong tab. :)